# Application shown as threat by AVG

Tags: c#, .net, security, firewall, antivirus

I am working on project in VB.Net that includes Socket Communication and embedded HTTPListeners, this is a group of applications that intercommunicate using Sockets. My problem is from few days I received report of Anti-virus (AVG) showing one of executable as threat.

Looking into the matter I was thinking to replace sockets with NamedPipes but still http listener would remain there.

How can I solve this problem

Comment: Is it viral in nature? Are you doing anything to hide the application from the user?

Comment: It remains hidden but has icon in notification area to allow user to turn it off but it can be restarted by other applications if they need its services.

Comment: It's not likely that the sockets or the http listener is the cause of your problems.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As you explained your application remains hidden, does network activity this makes your application to blocked by firewalls (security applications).
If you don't need network access consider other means of IPC (like namedpipes as you said) than sockets as you don't have to bother for port already being used type of errors.

but as others suggested you should send them your executable, stating as false positive.

This [link](http://www.geekstogo.com/forum/topic/273320-where-to-submit-false-positives-to-antivirus-and-security-vendors/) contains information to submit your application to AVG and other security vedors.

Answer (score 6):

I assume your code does not do bad thing so I would actually not change anything. Why should you try and workaround an overly sensitive tool? Contact AVG and submit it as false positive.

Answer (score 5):

You should send them your executable, stating it is detected a as threat, which is a false positive.

Answer (score 2):

Add some installation code to simply disable AVG or uninstall it. That should learn them not to give false positives.

This is not a serious answer though!

Comment: Sure, turn the false positive into a genuine positive. Saves AVG some work anyway. :)